# Content Shifting Between md- and sm- Breakpoints

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Total Bootstrap n00b here. I'm trying to clean up/modify [a resume site built with a simple site builder](http://collinscentral.com/stack-exchange-help/).

When I resize the browser to check its responsiveness, I'm getting strange behavior. Specifically, I'm trying to understand why when I reduce the browser size the photo switches to the left side before going full width as stipulated in the "col-sm-12" style. (I want the photo to float to the left of my content, except on mobile where they will be stacked.)

**It goes from this:**
[image]

**To this:** 
[image]

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-7 col-md-push-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="text-align:center">
                    <img class="editContent img-responsive" src="assets/images/content/upload/brand-book01.png" style="border-top-left-radius: 0px; border-top-right-radius: 0px; border-bottom-right-radius: 0px; border-bottom-left-radius: 0px; opacity: 1;">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-md-pull-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <h2 class="editContent" style="text-align: left; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 34px; letter-spacing: 1px; font-style: normal; text-transform: none;">Creating a Brand Book</h2>
                    <div><p class="editContent mb-50" style="text-align: left; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 16px; letter-spacing: 1px; font-style: normal; text-transform: none;">In 2015, Acme Co. was acquired by Big Conglomerate and in a matter of months we began to open physical retail stores. I proposed that we create a brand book to insure a consistent brand experience online and in stores. We formed a team and created a document that is now used across the organization.</p></div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Why is there an intermediate stage between the "col-md" formatting, which I like, and the "col-sm"/"col-xs" formatting which I also like?

Answer (score 0):

**Just Remove This Class Form div: `content-v-align`**

```
<div class="row content-v-align">
        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-push-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="text-align:center">
                    <img class="editContent img-responsive" src="assets/images/content/upload/brand-book01.png" style="border-top-left-radius: 0px; border-top-right-radius: 0px; border-bottom-right-radius: 0px; border-bottom-left-radius: 0px; opacity: 1;">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-md-pull-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <h2 class="editContent" style="text-align: left; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 34px; letter-spacing: 1px; font-style: normal; text-transform: none;">Creating a Brand Book</h2>
                    <div><p class="editContent mb-50" style="text-align: left; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 16px; letter-spacing: 1px; font-style: normal; text-transform: none;">In 2015, Acme Co. was acquired by Big Conglomerate and in a matter of months we began to open physical retail stores. I proposed that we create a brand book to insure a consistent brand experience online and in stores. We formed a team and created a document that is now used across the organization.</p></div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

---

**After Remove The Class `content-V-align` from the Div its Look Like This In Mobile View:**

[image]

Comment: This fixes the problem, but creates a new one. I *do* want the image to be vertically centered within the gray band at larger browser sizes. Is it not possible to do both? Can you elaborate on why removing the v-align tag makes a difference in the first place?

Comment: @MichaelCollins Your Image is already in center position as per css are define you can checked it,

Comment: after removing `content-v-align` because as per this class css, its display in row not in colums , i just remove the that class and default its display vertically center on the top of the text as per output !!

Answer (score 0):

Because you used `pull` and `push` class for medium screen(992px to 1199px). if you want same result for small screen(768px to  991px) use `sm-pull` and `sm-push` class for that

```
<div class="col-md-7 col-md-push-5 col-sm-push-5 col-sm-7 col-xs-12" style="text-align:center">
    <img class="editContent img-responsive" src="assets/images/content/upload/brand-book01.png" style="border-top-left-radius: 0px; border-top-right-radius: 0px; border-bottom-right-radius: 0px; border-bottom-left-radius: 0px; opacity: 1;">
</div>
<div class="col-md-5 col-md-pull-7 col-sm-pull-7 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
    <h2 class="editContent" style="text-align: left; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 34px; letter-spacing: 1px; font-style: normal; text-transform: none;">Creating a Brand Book</h2>
    <div>
        <p class="editContent mb-50" style="text-align: left; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 16px; letter-spacing: 1px; font-style: normal; text-transform: none;">In 2015, Acme Co. was acquired by Big Conglomerate and in a matter of months we began to open physical retail stores. I proposed that we create a brand book to insure a consistent brand experience online and in stores. We formed a team and created a document that is now used across the organization.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is one more div on top of this, where `<div class="row content-v-align">` are defined so !! :)